# Twitch channels status Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, twitch

I'm trying to make a Chrome extension to help with streaming on Twitch.

I don't have any error in the console, nothing, just a blank popup under my extension icon.

Here is my code:

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/twitchplayspokemon', function(channel) {

    if (channel["stream"] == null) {
        window.alert("offline");

    } else {
        window.alert("online");

    }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Twitch Status</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is of no use to anyone. What errors of you get? If the code runs how it what it is doing (or not doing) different to what you want to have happen?

Comment: I don't have any error in the console, nothing, just a blank popup under my extension icon

Comment: use the popup console, not the other two consoles.

Comment: Relevant: [Debugging tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) from documentation that shows how to access the popup console.

Answer (score 1):

When you visit the api.twitch.tv URL you see a 400 error code which is a bad request. There is a message added to it saying your client id is not specified... You need to add that to your URL after registering.

Twitch gives a good explanation [here](https://blog.twitch.tv/client-id-required-for-kraken-api-calls-afbb8e95f843#.7r4fo2xar). Check that out first, it should help you a lot.

Comment: You're right, thanks ! I can log the object with the code they give.

Comment: You're welcome. You should mark the post as the answer, otherwise people might think you're still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally clear on what you're attempting to do or asking, and not to grave dig, but here's a bit of helpful info, and keep in mind this is with the **new Twitch API** so differences considering the age of this post should be expected.

This was taken directly from one of my projects, so apologies if its not quite direct, just let me know if you'd want some more specific help! :)

```html
<?php
// Channel information
$clientID = 'clientID';
$twitch_channel = 'channel';

//// Twitch API call
$twitch = json_decode(curl_get_file_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/'.$twitch_channel.'?client_id='.$clientID), true);


// Some other helpful API Data

$game = $twitch['game'];
$status = $twitch['status'];
$views = $twitch['views'];
$followers = $twitch['followers'];

// Grabs the status of your stream so we can display different information below based on your status.
$stream = json_decode(curl_get_file_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'.$twitch_channel.'?client_id='.$clientID), true);
$viewers = $stream['stream']['viewers'];
$online = false;
if ($stream['stream'] != NULL) {
$online = true;}


// If you want to output that a channel is playing X game for X amount of viewers while pulling their title.

if($online){ echo 'playing ' .$game. ' for ' .number_format($viewers). ' viewers'; } else { echo 'offline'; } ?>
```